# Sorting and filtering the full paginated Antd Table

Tags: javascript, user-interface, react-redux, frontend, antd

I am using the Ant Design library for the project and the table element, in particular.

The question is how to make the sorters and filters work for the whole table, not just the first paginated page?

I am looking for the front-end solution because creating the back-end methods isn't suitable for the project.

```
  export default class BookTable extends React.PureComponent<BooksTableProps> 
  {
     private readonly columns: ColumnProps<Book>[] = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',           
        key: 'name',
        defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
        sorter: (a, b) => {return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)},
        render: (text, record) => <span>{record.name}</span>,
      },...
     ]
     render() {
        const {
        loading,
        pagination,
        books,            
     } = this.props;

     return (
        <div>           
          <Table          
            bordered
            columns={this.columns}
            dataSource={books}          
            loading={loading}
            pagination={pagination}
            onChange={this.handleTableChange}
          />
        </div>                
     )
   }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Raman! Could you include your entire component in the question so it will be easier for us to help you?

Comment: UPD: added the entire component, still for the solution. 
Thx for the welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supported out of the box. Once you define `sorter` it's used for all the `dataSource`. So, once you click on sorted column - all your data gets sorted.

Not very obvious, but you can take a look at [this example](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-grouping-columns). If you sort by `age` - the whole table data gets sorted.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, now it is clear!
I also sorted out that the problem was in my own custom pagination.

Answer (score 2):

If column has `string` values set

```
sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
```

If column has `integer` values set

```
sorter: (a, b) => a.number - b.number
```

If columns has `buttons` only, set

```
sorter: true
```

For more sorting options: [Array Sort Compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)